# Simple Question that I got back when I was in school

Tags: wordplay, anagram

This is gonna be my first question or puzzle. Hope this wouldn't be easy for you. What is the word that can be derived from ICE AND OUT?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Please don't post answers in comments, post with spoilers instead (well, not now that Rosie F already posted the same answer).

Comment: I still think that posting answers in comments should not be allowed although someone else has already answered the question @NaeemShaikh

Comment: @KevinL I had commented seconds before the accepted answer was posted.. anyways deleted my comment

Comment: Yep, I know but I opened this question and suddenly saw the answer. I believe that would be unpleasant for other users too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is

> education

but you should be

> cautioned

that there are 3 reasonably common answers.